# How can I style the nested blocks from the parent block in wordpress gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

**Structure**

```
- > Custom Parent Block 
    -> Custom Child Block
         -> Inner Blocks
    -> Custom Child Block
         -> Inner Blocks
```

*Requirement*
I want to have a section in the Inspector view where I can change the style(spacing, background color, text color, etc) of the child component of type custom-child-block.

Right now I can have the styles in the custom Child Block, but I cannot maintain uniformity.

*Example Cases*

- Accordion - Here we can have tabs and the tabs content area which could have the same style.
- Slides - All the items could have the same Border Styles

Please Note : There is provision to enable support for dimensions, background color and text color for the block, but how can I add a section where I can add the same support but for child elements.

**Ideal Solution**

- I mark certain CSS Variables in the child block like --border-child and update the variable values from the parent Inspector view.

Answer (score 0):

[Block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) can be used to provide the attribute values from the *Custom Parent Block* attributes to the *Custom Child Blocks*.

For your scenario, the Inspector Controls would be in the *Custom Parent Block* to set the value of a custom "border" block attribute. The *Custom Child Blocks* then [use the context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/#consuming-block-context) to get the value of the Parent - very useful with `InnerBlocks`.

With properties like background color or text color, enable [Block Supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-supports-in-static-blocks/) on the *Custom Parent Block* to apply the inbuilt CSS classes to the block. Next, provide the selected class to the children - or alternatively handle the styling with CSS selectors that apply to descendants of `.parent-block-name` with `--example-style` applied.

Comment: Thank you so much, S. Walsh, for answering my question. I am extremely grateful and would like to express my appreciation for taking the time to provide a detailed answer and assisting me.

I am still relatively new to programming blocks, and although I read through your response, I found it challenging to grasp how to utilize context in my particular scenario.

If you could provide a simplified example or any guidance that could help me move forward, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As you were asking S.Walsh for a more detailed explanation, here is an example:

1. Define the attributes in the block.json file.
2. Apply them to your children

**block.json:**

```
"attributes": {
    "backgroundColor": "string"
},
```

This will allow the input of a background color, but no text color.

**edit()**

```
import { InnerBlocks, InspectorControls, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { ColorPalette, PanelBody } from '@wordpress/components';
...
        <InspectorControls style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
            <PanelBody title={'Color'}>
                <p><strong>Select a backdrop color:</strong></p>
                <ColorPalette
                    value={backgroundColor}
                    onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ backgroundColor: value })}
                ></ColorPalette>
            </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>,
...
```

**save()**

```
export default function save({ attributes }) {
return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
                <div className="backdrop" style={{backgroundColor:attributes.backgroundColor}}></div>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
    </div>
)
```

}

It would also be nice to use the "supports" attribute in the block.json file, but that has some problems. I posted a question about that [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-proper-way-to-apply-styles-to-children-in-custom-blocks/#new-topic-0).

More generally, I can recommend this video for block development:
https://youtu.be/v00m1PaRaJ0